# Good practices for formatting simulation output

Tags: simulation

This is almost a programming question, but geared towards physicists.

Suppose I am writing a piece of software that takes some system parameters as input and then calculates something from it, in my case a spectral function $A(k,\omega)$.

When I want to just take the output and feed it to gnuplot, I should make the program output a simple table with one column for the $k$-values, one for $\omega$ and one for $A(k,\omega)$.

But then I cannot store there all the additional information, such as what parameters were used. And maybe I want to store in that output some additional debugging information such as intermediate quantities. In my example, the spectral function is obtained from the self energy, so in some situations I might want to look at the self energy directly.

I do not want to constantly hack the source code depending on what output I want. It would be nicer if *all* the relevant data of a "run" would be present in a single file/entity but so that it is still easy to extract tables I can feed to gnuplot.

Not wanting to reinvent the wheel and develop a full-blown file format, are there some "standards" around that are best used when creating, processing and storing data from calculations or simulations? Maybe even in an SQL database format?

Comment: This is on topic on yet-to-be-made [computation science](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/28815/computational-science?referrer=4pEy7Pj-D8kbaDTh4NmFiQ2) proposal.

Comment: It is also on-topic on Stack Overflow, because it is fundamentally a programming topic. You want to keep the meta data with the data. I always emitted files with meta data in the comments as seen by the target tool, but in a format that I could parse. Say lines beginning with '#' are comments to both, but lines beginning with '##' are meta data to be processed by my tools (which I think works for gnuplot).

Comment: My intention is to migrate this to SO, but I will allow some time for comments. You can try to change my mind.

Comment: Since I also have an SO account I wouldn't mind :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are dozens of methods, and none too good; I'll share two mine:

1. If the program is worth it, I add a small parser of config files. Then I just make a cofig, let's say, `SimA.in`, and simulator makes a bunch of files with corresponding data `SimA.paths`, `SimA.stats`, `SimA.log`, etc. Unless the names are unique and I add version of the code to log, this makes the results fully reproducible and the simulation itself portable enough to be easily manageable.
2. If not, I just wrap a code a bit and use [R](http://www.r-project.org/) as a host. Then I just return all the arrays and scalars (R data structures are very flexible, and it is easy to cast native R or C structs) and use R to manage, save/load and of course visualize and analyse the data. Moreover, with Sweave and CacheSweave the whole executing, analysis and reporting can be bunched in an elegant bunch, fully reproducible with one command.

If you want an "enterprise" solution, try [NetCDF](http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetCDF) or [HDF5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_Data_Format). But I feel it may be an overkill here.

And of course a version control of the simulator code is a must. But that's obvious =)

Answer (score 0):

For a project I'm currently working on that uses Python and C++ (via SWIG), I'm planning to use a short python script as input file. So, in a way, I'll be 'hacking the source' to change parameters, but in an interpreted language, not a compiled one.

Currently, I plan to have an input file like `parameters.py`, and use it like `from parameters import params`. But that might be too dependent on correct syntax.

```
params = {
"foods" : ["spam", "beans", "eggs"],
"costs" : [199, 4, 1],
"customerAge" : 23,
}
```

Another option might be to just define the variables at the script level in `parameters2.py`. This loses the nice dictionary packaging, but makes it a little harder for the user to mess it up. And it probably wouldn't be to hard to write a 'parser' that puts those script-level variables into a nice dictionary. A plus to method is that the user could parameterize things that weren't originally considered--`from parameters2 import *` would overwrite previous definitions of those parameters. Of course, this might be bad if the user overwrites something important.

```
foods = ["spam", "beans", "eggs"]
costs = [199, 4, 1]
customerAge = 23
```

`parameters3.py` would use a class, though it is contraindicated by Python's persnicketiness about indentation. `from parameters3 import params`:

```
class params:
    foods = ["spam", "beans", "eggs"]
    costs = [199, 4, 1]
    customerAge = 23
```

I should also mention, for completeness, that our C++ code also defines a parameters class. That is, in our actual project, parameters.py is a SWIG wrapper for a corresponding C++ class. You'd use like `from parameters4 import params`. However, this allows only parameters that are already declared in the C++ class.

```
import parameters
params = parameters.Parameters()
params.foods = ["spam", "beans", "eggs"]
params.costs = [199, 4, 1]
params.customerAge = 23
```

Comment: I just realized you were concerned about output, not input. I suppose my musings are simply inapplicable then. Sorry.

Comment: I have further realized that there's a configparser module that does a much better job of the this anyway. I'll be moving to that next week for this particular project.